# Break script if the condition match with text file

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a script for checking the password for zip file. The passwords is stored in a text file. The script is working fine but I want to stop the script where the password is matched or can I export the csv file. can anyone help me with this

```
$passfile = Get-Content "C:\Users\parveen.kumar\Downloads\passwords.txt"
$7ZipexePath = "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"
$zipFile = "C:\users\parveen.kumar\Downloads\just.zip"
foreach ($password in $passwords)
{
    Write-Host $password
    & $7ZipexePath "t" $zipFile "-p$passfile"
    if (-Not $?)
    {
        Write-Host $password "This is incorrect password."
    } else {
        Write-Host $password "This is the correct password." -ForegroundColor Red
    } 
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for the [`break`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Break) keyword?

Comment: Yes, once the script match the correct password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$passfile = Get-Content "C:\Users\parveen.kumar\Downloads\passwords.txt"
$7ZipexePath = "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"
$zipFile = "C:\users\parveen.kumar\Downloads\just.zip"
foreach ($password in $passwords)
{
    Write-Host $password
    & $7ZipexePath "t" $zipFile "-p$passfile"
    if (-Not $?)
    {
        Write-Host $password "This is incorrect password."
    } else {
        Write-Host $password "This is the correct password." -ForegroundColor Red;Break
    } 
}
```